# How to Set Desktop shortcut icon different and task bar icon different for a QT Windows application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I need to set title.ico as my application icon and shortcut.ico as my desktop shortcut. Is there any way to do it in a Qt application itself while building?

Whenever the user right-clicks on my application and clicks on sendto->desktop(create shortcut), the shortcut should have shortcut.ico. But now it's always displaying title.ico.

I checked WinApi IShell_link but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also a beginner, but turns out this is possible. See this thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/45324/taskbar-icon-different-from-the-icon-of-the-window/8

Hope I understood you right. Enjoy!

Edit 2018-03-13:

1. Create your icon in diffrent sizes (e.g. 16px, 32px, ...) as an .ico (while on Windows), for further information visit: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html
2. Call `QWindow::setIcon()` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setIcon)
3. Profit. The icon should now be visible in the greater resolution in the taskbar, while the smaller one is choosen for the app window.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply @school_guy . I need to do for the shortcut appIcon is fine for me

Comment: So I would suggest to make the smaller versions (up to 32) with icon.ico and for the rest I would use shortcut.ico

Comment: @pra7 pls accept my answer if it was the one you needed!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.